# Parametric curve and differentials

Tags: calculus, parametric

The parametric curve C is within the intersection of the xy plane and the surface $x^2+y^2+13z^2+10xy+3xz+2yz+4z=12$. Suppose your parametric curve is $\mathbf{C}=(x=t,y=f(t))$ where f is a continuous, differentiable function.

Evaluate $f(1)$ and explain why the following equality always holds:
$10tf'(t)+10f(t)+2t+2f(t)f'(t)=0$

---

I'm not sure how to start this problem. Is C just the intersection between the surface and the plane? How do I link this between $f$?

(Any extra examples with the related topic would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the curve $\mathbf{C}$ is just the intersection between the surface and the  $xy$-plane, that is $z=0$.

Hence, if $x=t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y=f(t)$ we obtain
$$t^2+f^2(t)+13\cdot 0+10tf(t)+3t\cdot 0+2f(t)\cdot 0+4\cdot 0=12$$
that is
$$t^2+f^2(t)+10tf(t)=12.$$
What do we obtain by taking the derivative with respect to $t$ of the two sides of the above equation?

Note also $f(1)$ can be obtained by solving the equation $1+f^2(1)+10f(1)=12$.

Comment: You get the equality! The reason it always holds is because it's tangent to the two surfaces?

But how does f(1) come about? It doesn't seem like you can find an actual value for it

Comment: @nodel The equality holds because $t^2+f^2(t)+10tf(t)=12$ holds for all real $t$. $f(1)$ can be obtained by solving the equation $1+f^2(1)+10f(1)=12$.

Comment: Ah, so just to be clear, f(1) can't be calculated yet with the given information?

Comment: @nodel  There are two possible values for $f(1)$ that is $1$ and $-11$. Actually the curve $C$,  $x^2+y^2+10xy=12$ is a hyperbola and the line $x=1$ intersects $C$ into two points (one for each branch).

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I have an exam soon. So you'd be able to calculate an equation of the tangent line to the parabola then?

Comment: For example the tangent line at $(1,1)$ is $y-1=f'(1)(x-1)$ where $f'(1)$ comes form $10f'(1)+10+2+2f'(1)=0$ (with $f(1)=1$). What is $f'(1)$?

Comment: -1? And a similar process occurs for the tangent at (-11,f(-11))

Comment: @nodel Yes, and yes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a point in the intersection of the xy plane and the surface , then $z=0$. Hence

$x^2+y^2+10xy=12$.

If $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=f(t)$ is a parametrization of $C$, then

$t^2+f(t)^2+10tf(t)=12$.

Can you take it from here ?